# angular not getting users from mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I've been trying to output user and pass on node server cmd however it keeps showing me `[Object Object]`. Code below should work but its not, can someone guide me on this one.

```js
app.get('/loginDB', function (req, res){
console.log('I receive a GET req.');
    db.loginDB.find(function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs+ ' get me all users');
        res.json(docs);
    })
});
```

`db.loginDB.insert()` is working fine but couldn't make the `.find()` to work, or unless I'm missing something else here. Saw a tutorial and it should be just that really.

I called the `loginDB` GET from postman and it returns me all the users, so not sure why this `db.loginDB.find()` is not working.

Output from postman when calling `longinDB` GET.

```json
[
  {
    "_id": "578efd321c67550df897508b",
    "user": "user1",
    "pass": "pass1"
  },
  {
    "_id": "578efd581c67550df897508c",
    "user": "user2",
    "pass": "pass2"
  },
  {
    "_id": "578efdb29cccf62a7432f2da",
    "user": "user3",
    "pass": "pass3"
  }
]
```

Comment: Try printing it to console `console.log(JSON.stringify(docs));`.

Comment: Is there an error on your console?

Comment: what this console is silly, so its showing me all the data now when I remove the string + 'text'. Well in that case i'll just remove it and its okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you append a variable to a string, it will stringify the variable using .toString() method, so in a standard javascript object will output [object Object].

You should change this:

```
console.log(docs+ ' get me all users');
```

for this:

```
console.log(docs, ' get me all users');
```

Now you can see the javascript object, and the string correctly in console.

Comment: bah! been bashing my head and that was a simple make, anyway I've removed the string text now anyways but thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
console.log(docs+ ' get me all users');
```

into

```
console.log(docs, ' get me all users');
```

Now you can see the javascript object, and the string correctly in console.

and also in   `db.loginDB.find({},function(err, docs) { });`

```
app.get('/loginDB', function (req, res){
console.log('I receive a GET req.');
    db.loginDB.find({},function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs+ ' get me all users');
        res.json(docs);
    })
});
```

Comment: Yeah tried that too and its still giving me the same thing [object object]

Comment: I added the output I got back from postman which I'm also expecting on this .find() function.

Comment: it should work have you check that your `monogod` server is running ? and your api is hitting ?